Random Utility Model Multiple Choice Question. Which one is correct?

In this random utility model, which of the five statements is true? I've been thinking about this question ever since the exam... I said (B).

Could you please add a reference? Thanks a lot!

MPhil Economics – Econometrics exam at Oxbridge.

I believe the correct answer is (C). Both coefficients are identifiable. The cross-sectional variation identifies the alternative-specific coefficients.
It is probably easiest to see why if you assume $Z_n$ only takes two values and ignores the other variables. Then you observe two groups with different proportions of individuals choosing alternatives 1,2 and 3 respectively which is sufficient to pin down $\delta_1,\delta_2$ and $\delta_3$.
The same argument goes for $\beta_j$ here you just also have variation across alternatives.
However, something that would be not identifiable is $\beta_jC_j$.
So the identifying variation is the cross-section variation.

I find this tricky to believe, as technically (C) being true would imply (B) cannot be false. In our course, we emphasised that only differences in utilities for a given decision maker matter, so for decision maker attributes we cannot identify the deltas in levels – only their difference with respect to a control group (e.g. set delta_1 = 0).
